# How to reduce the noise of impulse in image?

Tags: image-processing

I want to remove the impulse noise in an image.
As I know the noise reduction methods is average.
but I think it doesn't make sense when I use the average method to reduce the noise in image. because, the the average methods don't know this noise is whether impulse noise or not.
So I want to know how to remove the impulse noise in an image?

would you give any hint?

Comment: How about sharing an image or two?

Answer (score 0):

Linear filters are not good for removing impulse noise.
Order statistics filters deliver better results as they preserve the image information better.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Median filter or a combination of opening/closing with the tiniest structuring element.